# Как получить HTML код со страницы (Idhttp)?

Tags: delphi, cookie

Никак не могу получить HTML код вот с этой страницы: http://brutezone.ru/srv/freshproxy/  она открывается довольно долго в обычном браузере, именно поэтому пробовал увеличивать тайм аут но это не помогло

использую такой код: (юзерагент и реферер указаны как у нормального браузера)

```
idhttp1.ConnectTimeout:=99999999999999;
idhttp1.readTimeout:=9999999999999999;
page:=idhttp1.Get('http://brutezone.ru/srv/freshproxy/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот держи рабочий код для твоей страницы.

на форму кинешь IdHttp,Button,Memo

в OnButton1Click напишешь

```
var
sl:TstringList;
s:string;
coc:string;
begin
IdHTTp1.Request.UserAgent:='Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.12';
IdHTTp1.Request.Host:='http://brutezone.ru/';
sl:=TstringList.Create;
sl.Text:=IdHTTp1.Get('http://brutezone.ru/srv/freshproxy/');
s:=sl.Text;
delete(s,Lastdelimiter('"',s),Length(s));
delete(s,1,Lastdelimiter('"',s));
coc:=sl.Text;
delete(coc,1,Ansipos('"',coc));
delete(coc,AnsiPos('"',coc),Length(coc));
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Text:='Cookie: '+coc;
sl.Clear;
sl.Text:=IdHTTp1.Get(s);
s:=sl.Text;
delete(s,1,AnsiPos('<textarea>',s));
delete(s,1,AnsiPos('>',s));
delete(s,AnsiPos('<',s),Length(s));
memo1.Text:=s;
end;
```

Откомпилируешь и по клику на кнопке будешь получать в мемо список проксей шаровых :)

а вот те свои игры с интервалами не помогут, там ставятся куки идет перенаправленние .

Comment: да действительно отвечает очень долго до минуты доходило.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так страница не доступна ведь.

Еще может делфи новый стоит, так только в делфи 7 работает в 2009 уже не так
там функцию писать нужно с кодировкой.

Comment: Все там доступно, просто большой список динамически генерируется.
код который я выложил работает и в Д7 и ДХЕ

Answer (score -1):

```
uses
  IdCompressorZLib, IdHTTP;

//...

function GetPageSource(AURL: string): string;
var
  AIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  AIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    AIdHTTP.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(AIdHTTP);
    Result := AIdHTTP.Get(AURL);
  finally
    AIdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  PageSource: string;
begin
  PageSource := GetPageSource('http://brutezone.ru/srv/freshproxy/');
  //...
end;
```

Comment: А Причем здесь ZLib ? Вы хоть смотрели страницу?

Comment: Он умешает размер страницы. 
Конечно это не обязательно.

Comment: Смотрел через снифер (HTTPFox под FireFox). Данного кода достаточно.